# Creating an infinite Silverlight ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm interested in creating an ItemsControl for Silverlight that "loops" the items.  When the user scrolls to the end of the list the ItemsControl should then show the first item(s) in the list.  If the user scrolls above the first item in the list the ItemsControl should show the last item(s) in the list.  It probably makes sense here for the ItemsControl to hold more items than it contains.  What's a good way to go about creating this control?  I'm planning to data bind the ItemsSource property so a custom collection could also work.

Comment: You'll have to create custom panel and implement MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods to do the inifite scroll thingy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn to the good doctor for help: http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/08/05/itemscontrol-n-is-for-natural-user-interface/